# If an element has ancestors with heights < 100%, is there a way to still make it the height of the browser window without using JS?

Tags: html, css, sass

Maybe there's a way to figure out the browser height and use it as a variable in sass? Or perhaps some sort of absolute positioning that only takes into account the window itself?

Comment: Sass is never sent to the browser, how do you figure this is going to work?

Comment: Sure, you can take it out of document flow in several ways, but your question here is not really fully formed.  Can you show some code or other context around the problem you are having?

Comment: @cimmanon - the OP speculates, rather than asks how to do this with sass

Comment: @ToniLeigh OP should have done basic research about the technologies they are asking about before posing a question.  Searching for "sass element height" would have given them their answer.

Comment: @cimmanon I do feel in some cases we're dealing with extremely inexperienced developers, hence still needing to ask when the evidence appears easy to understand for experts - I see no harm in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can use `position: fixed;` for starters, this will fix the element relative to the window and then `height: 100%` will make it take the full height of the window. This option will however take the element out of scroll.

A second way to do it would be by setting `position: relative;` on the `<html>` or `<body>` tag, then making sure all elements down the DOM tree to the target element were defaulted to `position: static;`. Finally, setting `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` on the target element would make it refer to the next element up the tree not set to static.

More on position here [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

I final way would be to use `vh` units. This unit is 1% of the current viewport height so a value of `100` will make the element 100% the height of the screen. [Support is not perfect](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), so provide a fallback.

Finally, sass is a pre-compiled language that never gets as far as the browser. It generated css which is then used by the browser and is used to add power to our css programming.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your use case, you might want to look at the `vh` unit. This unit allows you to specify a height relative to the browser height. E.g., 50vh will be 50% of the window height.

`vw` is also available for window width.

You can look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for example

The unit seems to be [supported across the main used browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)